Save Plot Zoom as .pdf in RStudio
I generated a heatmap that has different dimensions in the "preview" box in RStudio, compared to the Plot zoom (way more gene names at the right to see)
Saving to pdf is only saving the "smaller" version, see below.
Also adjusting width and height to that of the plot zoom is yielding an error in the generated pdf "the dimensions of this page are out-of-range".


How can I solve this problem?

When I save plots I generally select save as Image (rather than save as PDF) and adjust the width and height as needed. It can be an iterative process but it works for me.

Use the ggsave function to export your plot into a specific size, resolution and file format, instead of relying on the arbitrary size of a panel or window.

@BastiánOleaHerrera but this is unfortunately not a "ggplot2" plot...

I think saving your plots with graphic devices is the best option. You can check this post to learn how to do it. Basicaly, you can adjust the dimentions and resolution of your plot however you want. Be careful with the text sizes though, as they become smaller with bigger images sizes if you didn´t specify a unit when generating the plot.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
